# Perl: read file and re-arrange into columns

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a file that i want to read in which has the following structure:

**EDIT**: i made the example a bit more specific to clarify what i need

```
HEADER
MORE HEADER
POINTS 2 
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
VECTORS velocities
u1 v1 w1
u2 v2 w2
VECTORS displacements
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
```

The number of blocks containing some data is arbitrary, so is their order.
i want to read only data under "POINTS" and under "VECTORS displacements" and rearrange them in the following format:

```
x1 y1 z1 a1 b1 c1
x2 y2 z2 a2 b2 c2
```

I manage to read the xyz and abc blocks into separate arrays but my problem is to combine them into one.

I should mention that i am a perl newbie. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is made very simple using the *range operator*. The expression

```
/DATA-TO-READ/ .. /DATA-NOT-TO-READ/
```

evaluates to 1 on the first line of the range (the `DATA-TO-READ` line), 2 on the second etc. On the last line (the `DATA-NOT-TO-READ` line) `E0` is appended to the count so that it evaluates to the same numeric value but can also be tested for being the last line. On lines outside the range it evaluates to a *false* value.

This program accumulates the data in array `@output` and prints it when the end of the input is reached. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@output, $i);

while (<>) {
  my $index = /DATA-TO-READ/ .. /DATA-NOT-TO-READ/;
  if ($index and $index > 1 and $index !~ /E/) {
    push @{ $output[$index-2] }, split;
  }
}

print "@$_\n" for @output;
```

**output**

```
x1 y1 z1 a1 b1 c1
x2 y2 z2 a2 b2 c2
```

Comment: great, thanks. i actually prefer this approach because it stores the result in an array. and apparently this also works if the headerlines of each block are different. I can just repeat the operation over a second, different range

Comment: @djun: If you clarify that with an example, I am sure there is a cleaner way of doing things than *"repeating the operation"*. Please show the actual data you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the question so that it now pretty much resembles the actual file format.

Answer (score 1):

I only used 1 array to remember the first 3 columns. You can output directly when processing the second part of the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @first;                                  # To store the first 3 columns.
my $reading;                                # Flag: are we reading the data?
while (<>) {
    next unless $reading or /DATA-TO-READ/; # Skip the header.

    $reading = 1, next unless $reading;     # Skip the DATA-TO-READ line, enter the
                                            # reading mode.
    last if /DATA-NOT-TO-READ/;             # End of the first part.

    chomp;                                  # Remove a newline.
    push @first, $_;                        # Remember the line.
}

undef $reading;                             # Restore the flag.
while (<>) {
    next unless $reading or /DATA-TO-READ/;

    $reading = 1, next unless $reading;
    last if /DATA-NOT-TO-READ/;

    print shift @first, " $_";              # Print the remembered columns + current line.
}
```

Comment: awesome, works perfectly! and a million times shorter than anything i tried

Comment: If possible, could you answer me one question about your solution: After reading in the first part you remove the new-lines from the array, right? So how is it possible that the second part is appended always in the correct line? Or: How does shift know where one line ends?

Comment: @djun: I only remove newlines from the first 3 columns. There is still the newline after the 6th column which never gets into the array: it's printed directly.

Comment: thanks, not sure if i misunderstand you, but what i actually wanted to know is: After you remove the newlines from the first 3 columns, you add the the second set. How is it they are placed correctly, since, at this point, there are no more newline characters in the first set to indicate where the 2nd set belongs? Sorry if i just misunderstood you

Comment: @djun: I keep the lines in an array, not in a single string.